# How to change color of span inside select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change span color to red in select option?
in js fiddle i want to change color of `<span class="myError">This is a required field.</span>` to red color [image]

```css
select{
  color: green;
}
select option { color: black; }

select option .myError{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<select >
 <option value="">Color:
 <span class="myError">This is a required field.</span>
 </option>
 
 <option value="17">Color: Midnight Blue</option>
 
 <option value="18">Color: Radar Red</option>
 
 </select>
```

Comment: An option element cannot have any child elements. you should consider using select plugins for this

Comment: In fact, you cant do this. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: ok thanks @AlexanderDemichev .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fancy idea using an overlay above the select and `mix-blend-mode`, then I control the change of color using CSS varibale.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
   $(this).parent().attr('style','--color:'+$(this).find(':selected').data('color'));
})
```

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  --color:red;
}

.select:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 40px;
  background: var(--color);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Color: This is a required field. </option>
 
 <option value="17" data-color="blue">Color: Midnight Blue</option>
 
 <option value="18" data-color="pink">Color: Radar Red</option>
 
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After rendering DOM you can inspect element it, you will see span will be remove. That's why css style properties are not working because there is not span or class `.myError` exist.

In other words option tag cannot allow other tags.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a html tag inside `<option>` tag. However you can achieve this using css:

```css
select{
  color: red;
}
select option { color: black; }

select option:first-child{
  color:red
}

.mid-blue{
  color: #0000CD;
}

.radar-red{
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<select >
 <option value="">Color:This is a required field
 </option>
 
 <option class='mid-blue' value="17">Color: Midnight Blue</option>
 
 <option class='radar-red' value="18">Color: Radar Red</option>
 
 </select>
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work in Google Chrome on Mac OSX;